# how to launch Print dialog from application as like from word pad in wince

Tags: winapi, mfc, windows-ce

I am trying to launch default print dialog from application , but it is not coming up. I am able to launc print dialog from wordpad application it is also printing the decument but, when i am trying to do the same nothing is happn. here is code for show print dialog:-

```
PAGESETUPDLG printDialog;

ZeroMemory(&printDialog, sizeof(printDialog)); 

printDialog.lStructSize = sizeof(printDialog); 

printDialog.hwndOwner = NULL; //or = NULL  

PageSetupDlg(&printDialog);
```

pls tell me how to achive this...

regards,

Mukesh

Comment: Does your OS image include Common Dialog Support (`SYSGEN_COMMDLG`)?

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted runs fine in a test app I knocked up, so technically there's nothing wrong with the code.

If you specify the hwndOwner as NULL, as in your example code, the print dialog opens as a modeless dialog, which could be opening *behind* your application's GUI - your code may therefore be correctly opening the dialog, you're just not seeing it.  As a modeless dialog doesn't stop you interacting with the window that spawned it, you would be able to fully interact with your main GUI, not realising the print dialog is sitting behind it.

Can you not specify the hwndOwner?  It should really be the handle of the window that's opening the print dialog, so that, as I mention above, it stops the user interacting with the main window whilst the printer settings are configured.